# Flex box issue on Safari — mobile and desktop

Tags: css, mobile, safari, flexbox, mobile-safari

The horizontal rule on the right overlaps the text in Safari on desktop and mobile.
How can I prevent the overlap?
[image: Safari on right]

http://codepen.io/simply-simpy/pen/EyENLr

```css
h2 {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 3.125vw;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

h2:after {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-left: 1.875vw;
  width: 100%;
}

h2:before {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1.875vw;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>precision</h2> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `flex-grow: 1;` instead of `width: 100%;` on your `h2:before` and `h2:after` will solve the issue.

```css
h2 {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 3.125vw;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

h2:after {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin-left: 1.875vw;
    flex-grow: 1;         /* <--- Replace */
}

h2:before {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1.875vw;
    flex-grow: 1;         /* <--- Replace */
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>precision</h2> 
</div>
```

Comment: This also fixed an issue with multiple words stacking: http://codepen.io/simply-simpy/pen/LkdxVG

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help :)